# which is better option between PhoneGap and normal java code to retrieve and store data on server

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create an application in android that will store the data on the server and retrieve the data from the server.So which one is better between PhoneGap and native java

Comment: If it just has to be an android app then it should definitely be a native app. Why use phone gap.

Comment: If you are targetting multiple platforms, go for `Phonegap` or `Intel XDK`, which is based on web technologies: HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Else, develop natively, in java.

Answer (score 0):

well since it is for android , java( for android )  is definetly better. although phonegap can be used for multiplatform , it reduce the performance of your app.

in summary , use phonegap for fast solutions for multiplatform app. but since your developping just for android  , use the java native